# Keep last three versions of a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have written an update script for a CMS running on my server and want to automatically delete older backups than the last three versions.
My current attempt looks like this:

```
dir=$(cd $GHOSTDIR/versions && ls  -1rd */ | tail -n +4)
keep=$(cd $GHOSTDIR/versions && ls -1rd */ | head -3)
echo "Deleting older versions" && echo $dir && echo "and keeping the last three versions as a backup:" && echo $keep
cd $GHOSTDIR/versions && ls -1rd */ | tail -n +4 | xargs rm -rf
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't delete older versions than the latest three but as the naming scheme changed from vX.Y.Z to X.Y.Z (e.g. "v4.1.0" to "4.5.0") only everything between the newest version (4.5.0 in this example) and the two "v" versions.
How can I modify it so that the directory creation date is being used instead of the name?

Comment: try `find $GHOSTDIR/versions -type d -name '*v4.1*' -not -newermt 'some date'` or  `find $GHOSTDIR/versions -type d -name '*v4.1*' -not -newerBt 'some date'`

Comment: There is a mix of directories with "v" and without "v" at the beginning.

Comment: `find ~/tmp -type d \( -name '4.1.*' -or -name 'v4.3*' \) -and -not -newermt '2019-05-01'`

Comment: Aside: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); [BashFAQ #3: How do I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)

Comment: I would use snapshots on a COW filesystem, but anyway... anything wrong using the -t option of ls? (assuming that mtime can be used instead of creation time of course)